# Non-printable characters were found is coming when I check my wordpress theme by theme check plugin

Tags: wordpress-theming

I want to upload a wordpress theme in wordpress.org. But it was rejected from theme check plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/). When I check the theme by using theme check plugin, then several errors is coming. Please check the screenshot-
http://awesomescreenshot.com/06022b3048
Please help me to fix the issues.
Happy codding!

Comment: I have fixed the issue myself. I have used UTF-8 without BOM.